# LaunchSettings.json can't handle \n

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, csproj

I'm have a Project with a LaunchSettings.json
it looks like this

LaunchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Profile 1": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "D:\\work\\test.exe",
      "commandLineArgs": "-compopath:D:\\Test\\TbTest\\Tw.TestImp\\TestImp\\bin\\Debug\\net4.8",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  }
}
```

but the commandlineArgs are messed up when i look into the Main
argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkhZs.jpg) the "...\net" has changed to "...\net" so my programm is thinking it is a Newline.

The Same happens with the executablePath if it contains a \n in LaunchSettings it dosn't find the Programm.

[Program Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkhZs.jpg)

Any solutions
Sounds like a bug for me

edid:

I added the Project's to Github so everyone can try it out. https://github.com/TorstenDB/LaunchSettings

It Only happens with **Visual Stdudio 2022**

Comment: Hi @TorstenB, how do you read the json file data? It works fine on my side.

Comment: what do u mean by reading it ? I'm starting it from Visual Studio 2022  select profile and start Debugging.

Comment: Hi @TorstenB, pls share your code and which variable you add the watch in visual studio.

Comment: i uploaded the Project on github u can download them and try it by youreself. TbImpl just called TstTest.exe with an arg and ther u can see the problem https://github.com/TorstenDB

Comment: I just found out, it just happens on Visual Studio 2022. so i reported it to Microsoft https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/post/10169831

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can us forward slashes ( / ) instead of backward slashes ( \ ) on Windows

Its seems they fixed it with Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.3.6 can't reproduce it anymore.